# HashMap вручную написать

Tags: java, map, java-hashmap

Нужно делать свою HashMap, ну т.е. чтобы `Map[x] = (String Key, Integer Value)`,
где х вычисляется по фурмуле, например `Сумма Ascii в Key % Размер Map`

Все облазил, не могу найти как имлементировать Маp, чтоб вручную указывать место сохранения `Map[x] = (String Key, Integer Value)`.

```
Map<String, String> map[] = new Map[3];
map[0].put("1", "Jan");
map[1].put("2", "Feb");
map[2].put("3", "Mar");
```

выдает

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at UB4_Anders.HashMapMain.main(HashMapMain.java:36)
```

Comment: `map[]` - это массив из объектов типа `Map`. `map[0].put` - попытка добавить элемент в первый `Map` из этого массива. Вы уверены, что это ровно то, что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: нет не уверен я столкнулся впервые с темой Map, мне нужен HashMap[100] например, где я буду вставлять пары ключь/значение на позиции, вычиляемые по формуле Список[x] = "Бухгалтер, 1000", где х = 1000 % 3 например

Comment: Если вы реализуете свою `Map` (`public class MyMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> { ... }`) и хотите сделать особый способ добавления пары ключ-значение, то кроме метода `public V put(K key, V value)` придётся сделать отдельный метод (например, `public V put(int keyCode, K key, V value)`).